# Dump (pickle) in new line Python

Tags: python, file, delimiter

So i want to write each element of a list in a new line in a binary file using Pickle, i want to be able to access these dictionaries later as well.

```
import pickle    
with open(r'student.dat','w+b') as file: 
for i in [{1:11},{2:22},{3:33},{4:44}]:
    pickle.dump(i,file)
file.seek(0)
print(pickle.load(file))
```

Output:

```
{1: 11}
```

Could someone explain why the rest of the elements arent being dumped or suggest another way to write in a new line?
I'm using Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all being dumped, but each dump is separate; to load them all, you need to match them with `load` calls.

```
import pickle    
with open(r'student.dat','w+b') as file: 
    for i in [{1:11},{2:22},{3:33},{4:44}]:
        pickle.dump(i,file)
file.seek(0)
print(pickle.load(file))


import pickle    
with open(r'student.dat','w+b') as file: 
    for i in [{1:11},{2:22},{3:33},{4:44}]:
        pickle.dump(i,file)
file.seek(0)
for _ in range(4):
    print(pickle.load(file))
```

If you don't want to perform multiple loads, pickle them as a single data structure (e.g. the original `list` of `dict`s all at once).

In none of these cases are you writing newlines, nor should you be; pickle is a binary protocol, which means newlines are just another byte with independent meaning, and trying to inject newlines into the stream would get in the way of loading the data, and risk splitting up bits of data (if you actually read a line at a time for loading).

Comment: Thanks! Could you recommend a source to read up(even a video is ok) on binary files, what they are exactly etc. as im just a beginner?

Comment: @sam: I don't even know where to begin here. A binary file is the least restrictive definition available; it can include bytes with any value at all. The meaning is dependent on what format you write it in (in this case, pickle). Point is, if your protocol involves writing *arbitrary* bytes (pickle does) then trying to insert *any* bytes that are not part of that format is doomed to failure without taking extreme measures (e.g. prefixing each formatted part with a length so you know when to switch modes). A beginner shouldn't be trying to mix stuff like this.